# android make new version for build.gradle

Tags: android, github, fork, build.gradle

I've forked Android project from GitHub, clone using SourceTree make my changes and want to make a new version for using that in my other app by gradle version increasing

Now I want to have something like this in my `buil.gradle` file

older is `compile 'com.github.lib:0.3.1'`

and the new one `compile 'com.github.lib:0.3.2'`

How  can I do this?

Comment: you have to make it an android library, upload it to maven central, bintray, jitpack io with different group id and artifact id and then you can use it!!!

Answer (score 0):

Go to your `build.gradle` (Module:app) file :

[image]

And update the dependencies :

[image]

Comment: my problem is to make forked project library (something about converting app to lib)